# Angular directive for detect screen size

Tags: angular, angular-directive

Help me, please, how can I do that?

I want to apply directive to the divs, it will be show or hide content depending of it's value, for example: *ifViewportSize="'mobile'"

```html
<div *ifViewportSize="'large'">PC</div>
<div *ifViewportSize="'small'">Mobile</div>
```

Directive: (rezult in console.log) https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wdl8ee

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[ifViewportSize]'
})
export class IfViewportSizeDirective {

size: string;

  config = {
    large: 992,
    medium: 768,
    small: 576
  };

  constructor(
    private elemRef: ElementRef,
    private vcRef: ViewContainerRef,
    private templRef: TemplateRef<any>) {

    window.onresize = (event) => {
      this.showElem();
    };
  }

  @Input() set ifViewportSize(size: string) {
    this.size = size;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.showElem();
  }

  showElem() {
    console.log('size: ',this.size);

    if (this.config[this.size] < window.innerWidth) {
      this.vcRef.clear();
      this.vcRef.createEmbeddedView(this.templRef);
    }
    else this.vcRef.clear();
  }

}
```

Directive works only in the last div. Please tell me why?

Also I tried to create (right here, on stackblitz) separately directives ifMobile и ifTablet.
I implemented there a function window.onresize, but again this function works only on the last div.

How can I fix it?
If this is a wrong way to detect the screen size, how can I do this right?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Instead of reinventing the wheel you might be able to find your solution using 
https://material.angular.io/cdk/layout/overview. With that package you can listen media query changes in your component and act on it accordingly

Comment: What are boundaries for Mobile, Table and PC screens in your case? `0 - 576` - mobile, `576 - 768` - tablet, `768 - 992` - PC?

Comment: @Jelle but I have to listen breakpointObserver in each component. Maybe is there a way that does not duplicate the code in all components?

Comment: @yurzui Yes, but this is for example, I tried to understand how to do such a problem and find the best practices.

Comment: @kompaniietst you can always create the observers in a separate service. Have that shared with the components that actually want to listen to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of `let directive with $implicit context` in angular being used with `structural directive` normally as below,

---

```
<div *ifViewportSize="let view=$implicit"> .... </div>
```

---

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, ViewContainerRef, TemplateRef, OnInit, Input, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

export enum VIEW{
  MOBILE ,
  TABLET ,
  PC 
}

@Directive({
  selector: '[responsive]'
})
export class IfViewportSizeDirective {

  view;

  config = {
    large: 1200,
    medium: 700,
    small: 500
  };

  constructor(private readonly viewRef: ViewContainerRef,
        private readonly templateRef: TemplateRef<any>) {  this.checkView();}

  ngOnInit(){
      window.addEventListener('resize', this.checkView.bind(this));
  }

 
  checkView() {
    this.viewRef.clear();

     console.log(window.innerWidth);
     if((0 < window.innerWidth) && (window.innerWidth < this.config['small'] )){
       
       this.view = VIEW.MOBILE;
       
     } else if((this.config['small'] < window.innerWidth) && (window.innerWidth < this.config['medium'])){

       this.view = VIEW.TABLET;
       
     } else if(this.config['medium'] < window.innerWidth){
      
      this.view = VIEW.PC;
     }
     
  
     this.viewRef.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef,{
                    $implicit: this.view
     });
    }
  

}
```

**[FULL DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-z7wkek?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)**

**NOTE**: *you can still optimize it.*

Answer (score 5):

### Update

The best solution would be not to reinvent the wheel but rather use `@angular/cdk/layout` functionality:

**if-viewport-size.directive.ts**

```
type Size = 'small' | 'medium' | 'large';

const config = {
  small: [Breakpoints.Small, Breakpoints.XSmall],
  medium: [Breakpoints.Medium],
  large: [Breakpoints.Large, Breakpoints.XLarge]
};

@Directive({
  selector: "[ifViewportSize]"
})
export class IfViewportSizeDirective implements OnDestroy {
  private subscription = new Subscription();

  @Input("ifViewportSize") set size(value: Size) {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    this.subscription = this.observer
      .observe(config[value])
      .subscribe(this.updateView);
  }

  constructor(
    private observer: BreakpointObserver,
    private vcRef: ViewContainerRef,
    private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>
  ) {}

  updateView = ({ matches }: BreakpointState) => {
    if (matches && !this.vcRef.length) {
      this.vcRef.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
    } else if (!matches && this.vcRef.length) {
      this.vcRef.clear();
    }
  };

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
<div *ifViewportSize="'large'">PC</div>
<div *ifViewportSize="'medium'">Tablet</div>
<div *ifViewportSize="'small'">Mobile </div>
```

**[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jrtbsa?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)**

**The benefits of using this solution:**

1. It avoids memory leak
2. Resize event is listed in a performant way(outside of Angular zone)
3. It doesn't remove and recreate template infinitely on resize but rather only once it hits breakpoint

### Previous answer

It works only for the last div because you're listening for resize event through `onresize` property which is **overrided be each directive**.

```
window.onresize = (event) => {
   this.showElem();
};

window.onresize = (event) => { <---- you completely replace onresize event
  this.showElem();
};
...
window.onresize = (event) => { <---- one more replacement
  this.showElem(); <-------------- only this handler will be executed 
};
```

You could use `@HostListener` instead but it [doesn't work in structural directives](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14191). So try using `window.addEventListener` instead:

```
ngOnInit() {
 window.addEventListener('resize', this.showElem);
 ...
}

showElem = () => { // <-- note syntax here
   ...
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  window.removeEventListener('resize', this.showElem);
}
```

> Note: I would also consider listening to `resize` even outside of
> NgZone via `ngZone.runOutsideAngular()`

Now, your resize handler should work.

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dtzsbq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)**

### But

- you're constantly removing template
- it's quite unclear how you're going to handle boundaries for all your sizes. Because mobile screen will be visible even for PC size since it meets condition `mobileSize < window.innerWidth`

Comment: Thanks a lot! It it looks logical and works. But can I ask, maybe you know other better solutions for the problem, like mine?

Comment: Yes, please take a look. I added alternative option